# Низкоуровневый GUI

Tags: gui, архитектура, c++

Начинаю осваивать C++, и возникла необходимость написать простой графический редактор в качестве учебного задания. Существенное ограничение состоит в том, что графическая библиотека позволяет лишь рисовать на экране фигуры и отслеживать координаты мыши. Поэтому необходимо самому реализовать какой-нибудь пользовательский интерфейс. Простая идея: создать отдельную иерархию классов, отвечающих за передачу события (то есть, к примеру, узел имеет список подузлов и проверяет совпадение координат в них, далее совпавший узел вызывает контроллер элемента интерфейса) не подходит, поскольку нужен drag-n-drop (например, изменение размеров прямоугольника). Как ещё можно реализовать подобное? Или, может быть, есть какие-либо руководства по теме?

Comment: > нужен drag-n-drop (например, изменение размеров прямоугольника)

Это не drag-n-drop.

> Как ещё можно реализовать подобное?

Именно так, как вы предположили.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Существенное ограничение состоит в том, что графическая библиотека позволяет лишь рисовать на экране фигуры и отслеживать координаты мыши.

Не совсем понятно сформулирован вопрос. Могу предположить, что Вы пишите о низкоуровневой архитектуре `GUI` в `Windows`. И цитата касается `GDI` и системы событий Windows (типа `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_PAINT` и т.п.).

Если мои предположения выше верны, то Вы упустили в цитате еще один существенный момент: помимо отрисовки и отслеживания координат, **эта архитектура так же позволяет управлять различными встроенными средствами `GUI`**, например:

- изменение размеров или перемещение окна,
- управление скроллбаром,
- управление системным меню окна
- организация и взаимодействие различных *виртуальных зон окна* (nonclient)<sup>[*deep*](http://ru.vingrad.com/Okna-v-fotoshope-id50b297f26ccc19606f08ffd8#findElement_E7045_50b29ee86ccc19606f099cb5_0)</sup>
- управление взаимодействием окон: интерфейсы SDI/MDI

Наверняка перечень не полный. Здесь он касается только 2-х событий: `WM_NCHITTEST` и `WM_NCACTIVATE` (ну и небольшой группы событий `WM_NCxxx`, если быть точным). Причем, все это приложение делает пассивно, т.е. не реализует на своей стороне какие-то дополнительные механизмы: система (Windows) просто посылает в окно сообщение с каким-то *базовым* набором параметров, приложение может его изменить по своему усмотрению и это повлияет соответствующим образом на работу `GUI`, который реализует сама `Windows`.

> нужен drag-n-drop (например, изменение размеров прямоугольника). Как ещё можно реализовать подобное?

Опять же, если я правильно понял вопрос, то Вы видите проблему в том, что зафиксировать положение курсора мыши над каким-то Вашим объектом Вам недостаточно, т.к. хотите, чтобы этот же "контроллер элемента интерфейса" получал и соответствующие события (WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_MOUSEMOVE и т.п.).

Проясните этот момент, и я расширю ответ, чтобы связать первую его часть со второй.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вы бы посмотрели на дату! Я уже давно забросил этот проект. Вообще там использовалась не GDI, а WinBGIm. Я так понимаю, здесь какой-то робот поднимает старые неотвеченные вопросы, поэтому давайте я просто приму ваш ответ, может быть, он кому-нибудь пригодится.

Comment: Да, действительно, на даты не посмотрел. `WinBGIm`, конечно, все в корне меняет. Спасибо за лояльность. Но я все же за релевантность в ответах, поэтому [внес на мету свое предложение](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2310/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2) относительно таких ситуаций.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос слишком велик чтобы ответить просто исходником.

Вот пара ссылок:

http://www.programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?t=185187

http://www.softtime.ru/cpp/read.php?id_forum=1&id_theme=1382

http://www.cyberforum.ru/visual-cpp/thread513534.html